# Extract some value without key from a json object

Tags: json, regex, elasticsearch

I am using **java** to extract a list of node ids from an elastic search running tasks response.

The response looks like this

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "ZKUuxQZpRCCcJ0njBM1P0A": {
            "name": "ZKUuxQZ",
            "transport_address": "127.0.0.1:9300",
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "ip": "127.0.0.1:9300",
            "roles": [
                "master",
                "data",
                "ingest"
            ],
            "tasks": {
                "ZKUuxQZpRCCcJ0njBM1P0A:118": {
                    "node": "ZKUuxQZpRCCcJ0njBM1P0A",
                    "id": 118,
                    "type": "transport",
                    "action": "indices:data/write/delete/byquery",
                    "start_time_in_millis": 1527808643421,
                    "running_time_in_nanos": 154234724059,
                    "cancellable": true,
                    "headers": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, I want to exact `ZKUuxQZpRCCcJ0njBM1P0A:118`. Can someone give me an example how to extract this information?

Option 1, **java** json parser. I wanted to write a response class and parse the json string, but `ZKUuxQZpRCCcJ0njBM1P0A:118` is not in the key:value format. I am not sure how to extract it.

Option 2, using regex. The node id part may also have `-` or `_`. Can someone provide a neat **java** regex solution? So far my regex is `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+\:[0-9]+`, I am not sure if this is safe enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Forget about option 2. Parsing JSON is a solved problem and soon you want to extract others things that are harder/impossible with regex.

Comment: Try this regex: [a-zA-Z0-9-_]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+:[0-9]*

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is by using `org.json` library and create `JSONObject` and using `keys()` you can get all the keys and use this to achieve your task

Add the following dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can do something like below:

```
String jsonString = "{\n" +
        "    \"nodes\": {\n" +
        "        \"ZKUuxQZpRCCcJ0njBM1P0A\": {\n" +
        "            \"name\": \"ZKUuxQZ\",\n" +
        "            \"transport_address\": \"127.0.0.1:9300\",\n" +
        "            \"host\": \"127.0.0.1\",\n" +
        "            \"ip\": \"127.0.0.1:9300\",\n" +
        "            \"roles\": [\n" +
        "                \"master\",\n" +
        "                \"data\",\n" +
        "                \"ingest\"\n" +
        "            ],\n" +
        "            \"tasks\": {\n" +
        "                \"ZKUuxQZpRCCcJ0njBM1P0A:118\": {\n" +
        "                    \"node\": \"ZKUuxQZpRCCcJ0njBM1P0A\",\n" +
        "                    \"id\": 118,\n" +
        "                    \"type\": \"transport\",\n" +
        "                    \"action\": \"indices:data/write/delete/byquery\",\n" +
        "                    \"start_time_in_millis\": 1527808643421,\n" +
        "                    \"running_time_in_nanos\": 154234724059,\n" +
        "                    \"cancellable\": true,\n" +
        "                    \"headers\": {}\n" +
        "                }\n" +
        "            }\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

Set<String> topLevelKeys = jsonObject.keySet();

for (String key : topLevelKeys) {
    Object value = jsonObject.get(key);

    if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
        JSONObject valueObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
        System.out.println(valueObject.toString());
    }
}
```

Extend this as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

So regex is too hacky and I figured it out using gson. I wish ElasticSearch can offer us some standard library to extract all kinds of responses. Here is my solution using gson.

```
import com.google.gson.*;
```

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String jsonString = "json_format elasticsearch reponse for listing running tasks"
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(content).getAsJsonObject();

    jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("nodes").entrySet().forEach(
            s -> {
                s.getValue().getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("tasks").entrySet().forEach( s2 -> {
                    System.out.println(s2.getKey());
                });
            });
}
```

It prints all the running task ids like the following. It's technically nodeId:taskId, but ES has a very vague description in their task API docs(It says you can use TASK_ID to check a status of a task, well that TASK_ID is nodeId:taskId).

`Mw-3i39gTHGxu5c8z9viQQ:503209021
DZ29LMsWR0aW9guWZTYe2Q:482931604
6CAbDZSWR8SfwZgnRT0qNg:494351185`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+:[0-9]*
```

You can find the test result here:

https://regexr.com/3qdug